# Find the best number of thread with Intel OpenMP : only 1 thread has better results than many threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, openmp, intel

Using multiples times the following type of loops in my code :

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, num_threads)
for(int i=0; i<F_matrix_A.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<F_matrix_A.size(); j++){
        F_previous_T[i][j] = F_previous[j][i];
    }
}

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, num_threads)
for(int i=0; i<F_matrix_A.size(); i++){
    for(int k=0; k<F_matrix_A.size(); k++){
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
            if(F_previous_T[i][k] != 0 && F_previous[k][j] !=0){
                Fisher_new[i][j] += F_previous_T[i][k]*F_previous[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the  best performances when I set before the parameter : `#define num_threads 1`

I am working on a work station with 64 cores (I see 128 processors when I do a `/proc/cpuinfo`). I think it is a pity to not be able to benefit from this high number of processes.

Is it due to the specific pragma that I use :

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, num_threads)
```

??

Is there other alternatives to get a lower runtime ? I saw on different forums that using with a pretty high number of processes could cause a significant overhead.

The size of my loop are typically of 1700x1700.

If someone had an idea, this would be fine to tell it.

**UPDATE 1 :** I have 2 versions of my code, one with `GNU g++` and the other with `Intel icpc`

1) I am using the "generic" following Makefile :

```
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
include $(MAKECMDGOALS).make
endif

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

$(MAKECMDGOALS): $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

1) For `GNU g++`, I compile with `gnu.make` file :

```
CXX = g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -fopenmp
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -c
LDFLAGS = -march=native
LDFLAGS =
SOURCES = main.cpp TSAF_gnu.cpp
EXECUTABLE = main_gnu.exe
```

2) For `Intel icpc`, I compile with `intel.make` file :

```
CXX = icpc -std=c++11 -O3 -xHost -qopenmp
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -c -I${MKLROOT}/include
LDFLAGS  = -mkl=parallel
LDFLAGS += -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64_lin -Wl,-rpath,${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64_lin -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_intel_thread \
          -lmkl_core -liomp5 -lpthread
SOURCES = main.cpp TSAF_intel.cpp
EXECUTABLE = main_intel.exe
```

A standard run takes about 3 minutes.

Comment: What are the compilation flags? Which optimization level do you use? Also, matrix of this size might be too small for parallel processing. How long takes the single-threaded run?

Comment: @DanielLangr I added an **UPDATE 1** to give you more informations.

Comment: From a quick glance: (1) you could scarcely write less cache-friendly access patterns, traversing one array row-major and the other column-major.  (2) The 'computational payload' of each loop is trivial. (3) `if` statements buried at the bottom of deep loop nests are a great way to confuse branch prediction at very high rates. (4) `schedule(dynamic, *small_chunk_size*)` might be the worst schedule to use for the problem.  Now, none of these may be avoidable for your application, but what you've written is almost a textbook example of when *not* to use OpenMP.

Comment: How about you get rid of that `if (...)` in the innermost loop and also get scrap the `schedule` clause? If any of the two factors is zero, the product will be zero anyway and multiplication is really fast. Also, `schedule(dynamic)` has *HUGE* overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `schedule(dynamic, num_threads)` is likely to cause *scalability issues*.

Indeed, with a matrix of size 1700 and 64 threads, the chunk size of the dynamic schedule policy is 64. Thus, the number of chunks is `floor(1700/64) = 26` which is far too small to feed the 64 threads!
Even with 32 threads, the *work balancing* is not very good. I think it is important to have at least 3-4 chunk per thread.

Increasing the *granularity* with the number of thread is weird. It is probably more relevant to set a granularity based on the input size. I advise to use either the `schedule(guided)` or `schedule(dynamic,chunksize)` with chunksize set to something like `max(F_matrix_A.size() / (num_threads * 4), 1)` (although using `schedule(dynamic,1)` should not be so bad if you do not add the `collapse`).

Alternatively, you can use *task* and *taskloops* directives.

Also note that if you work on a machine with multiple NUMA nodes (this is probably the case since there are 64 cores), you should be very *careful* with a *dynamic* scheduling because threads may access to *remote NUMA memory nodes* decreasing significantly the performances (this is clearly something you do *not* want in your memory-bound code).

**Update**: you can work on the two vertical side of the array simultaneously to significantly reduce the variability of the inner-loop computation time. The result would be something like that:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for(int i=0; i<(F_matrix_A.size()+1)/2; i++)
{
    // Upper-part
    for(int k=0; k<F_matrix_A.size(); k++)
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
            if(F_previous_T[i][k] != 0 && F_previous[k][j] != 0)
                Fisher_new[i][j] += F_previous_T[i][k]*F_previous[k][j];

    // Lower-part (do not perform the middle twice)
    if(i < F_matrix_A.size()/2)
    {
        const int i2 = F_matrix_A.size() - 1 - i;

        for(int k=0; k<F_matrix_A.size(); k++)
            for(int j=0; j<=i2; j++)
                if(F_previous_T[i2][k] != 0 && F_previous[k][j] != 0)
                    Fisher_new[i2][j] += F_previous_T[i2][k]*F_previous[k][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: `collapse(2)` is really a poor choice when the inner loop contains statements such as `Fisher_new[i][j] += ...` and the `j`-loop runs independently in all threads. There is no guarantee that two threads won't end up having the same value of `i`. On the opposite, that is very likely to be the case since you are suggesting chunk size that is a fraction of the matrix size.

Comment: I agree. It could cause data races. I think this is possible to do a `collapse(2)` with a an array reduction, but this is probably inefficient. So, I removed this part. Thank you.